# Why does python have to generate the full range to test if float in range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is really fast:

```
1 in range(100000000000000)
```

This is really slow:

```
1.5 in range(100000000000000)
```

Why does the full range have to be generated to know that `1.5` isn't in `range(X)` when `step` has to be an integer?

Comment: 1 in range will stop after the first element. How is the speed when you're checking an int that isn't in your range?

Comment: That's fast too. I would have thought that it's immediately obvious a number isn't in a range if the modulo of the number divided by the step isn't 0.

Comment: I guess optimizations are made if the element is an integer. 'hello' in range(100000000000) is slow too

Comment: @CorentinLimier I suppose it's as simple as that! `99999999.0 in range(100000000)` takes a long time but `99999999 in range(100000000)` doesn't.

Comment: My guess: floating points in ranges are tricky so they exhaustively search? But it should bail early from the search after it encounters a value in the range greater than the needle (the value its looking for)?

Comment: @AhmedFasih so in theory it would find 2 almost immediately and bail out of the example above quickly.. but it takes a long time so must have to populate a list with the full range of values first?

Comment: @SuperShoot yes I'm very confused!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we check the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7ecae3ca0bda3cacf3b0125bae0bc718a17cc071/Objects/rangeobject.c):

The contains function:

```
range_contains(rangeobject *r, PyObject *ob)
{
    if (PyLong_CheckExact(ob) || PyBool_Check(ob))
        return range_contains_long(r, ob);

    return (int)_PySequence_IterSearch((PyObject*)r, ob,
                                   PY_ITERSEARCH_CONTAINS);
}
```

It appears to check if it will use an integer or boolean method to check, and if not it uses the PY_ITERSEARCH_CONTAINS.

Comment: Even without knowing any c it’s clear what’s going on there so +1. Any thoughts on why? Too much of an edge case? Too expensive? Just not a function intended for floats?